# Страсти-мордасти. Откуда взялись и кто они такие?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов, прописная-строчная

[**Страсти-мордасти**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2628/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Из русской народной песни:
*Придут **Страсти-Мордасти,**

Приведут с собой Напасти,

Приведут они Напасти,

Изорвут сердце на части!

Ой, беда, ой, беда!

Куда спрячемся, куда?*
Выражение стало популярным благодаря Максиму Горькому (1868—1936), который так назвал один из своих рассказов (1912).
Иронически: о чем-то мнимострашном, о попытке напугать какими-либо россказнями и т. д.

Рассказ М. Горького называется [**Страсти-мордасти**](https://studfiles.net/preview/2973679/page:2/) ("мордасти" — с маленькой буквы).
В самой колыбельной "Мордасти" пишутся с большой буквы.

Откуда появились **Страсти-Мордасти**? Кто это такие?
И как всё-таки правильно: с маленькой или с большой буквы?

Answer (score 2):

В авторитетных источниках этимологии я не обнаружил.

Скорее всего второй компонент чистое фонетическое рифмованное "дополнение".
Таких много в русском: фокус-покус, фигли-мигли, шахер-махер... Иногда, впрочем, этот второй компонент народная этимология наделяет неким смыслом, подчас совершенно фантастическим; так, гоголь-моголь возводится к Гогу и Магогу и проч.

Страсти-мордасти тоже имеют подобные народные объяснения, убедительных версий среди них я не знаю, но вот наименее неправдоподобной выглядит отсылка к страстям сильным, которые невозможно скрыть, отражающихся на лице, то есть "морде", "мордасах".

Еще более "продвинутые" авторы соотносят мордасы со страстотерпием Христовым, то есть страсти-мордасти по такой версии - это муки Христовы. Собственно это та же версия, что и выше, только еще и Христос добавлен "для убедительности".

В любом случае современное значение достаточно далеко ушло от исходного значения слова страсть=страдание.

Совсем уж неправдоподобными выглядят попытки объяснить страсти измененным "здрасте".